# The attribute name is repeated twice in the error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I have a en.yml file

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    models:
      recipe: "Recipe"
    attributes:
      recipe:
        title: "Recipe title"
    errors:
      models:
        recipe:
          attributes:
            title:
              blank: "{{attribute}} cannot be left blank"
```

In my model I validate the presence of the title field

```
  validates_presence_of :title
```

However, the error message that I see on the page is something like this

```
Recipe title Recipe title cannot be left blank.
```

I cannot figure out why the attribute name is repeated twice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because rails prefixes the error message with the attribute name. You don't need `{{attribute}}` in the message. This would work as expected:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    models:
      recipe: "Recipe"
    attributes:
      recipe:
        title: "Recipe title"
    errors:
      models:
        recipe:
          attributes:
            title:
              blank: "cannot be left blank"
```

Comment: So can I prefix the error message with something like "Recipe {{attribute}} some message"?

Comment: As far as I know you can't do it like that (at least not for the "blank" message), because the name still would be added at the beginning of the message.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix that makes error messages more customizable (attribute names aren't shown in the beginning of the sentence). You can find it here : http://adamhooper.com/eng/articles/5